# Spark 1.6 Streaming consumer reading in kafka offset stuck at createDirectStream

Tags: scala, apache-kafka, spark-streaming, apache-spark-1.6

I am trying to read in the spark streaming offset into my consumer but I cannot seem to do it correctly.

Here is my code.

```
val dfoffset = hiveContext.sql(s"select * from $db")
dfoffset.show()
val dfoffsetArray = dfoffset.collect()
println("printing array of data")
dfoffsetArray.foreach(println)
val fromOffsets = collection.mutable.Map[TopicAndPartition, Long]()
for (i <- dfoffsetArray) {
  val topicAndPartition = (TopicAndPartition(i(1).toString, i(0).toString.toInt) -> (i(2).toString.toLong))
  fromOffsets += topicAndPartition
}

val kafkaParams = Map[String, String]("bootstrap.servers" -> serverName, "group.id" -> "test")
val topics = Array(topicName).toSet
//stuck here 
var directKafkaStream = KafkaUtils.createDirectStream[String, String, StringDecoder, StringDecoder](ssc, kafkaParams, topics)

directKafkaStream.foreachRDD(rdd1 => { ..
```

Here is the output from showing the dataframe

```
partition_number|topic_name|current_offset|
+----------------+----------+--------------+
|               0|TOPIC_NAME|          4421|
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

I am using spark 1.6 , Scala 2.10.5, kafka 10

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the official document shown [KafkaUtils.createDirectStream](https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.6.3/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka.KafkaUtils$@createDirectStream[K,V,KD<:kafka.serializer.Decoder[K],VD<:kafka.serializer.Decoder[V],R](ssc:org.apache.spark.streaming.StreamingContext,kafkaParams:Map[String,String],fromOffsets:Map[kafka.common.TopicAndPartition,Long],messageHandler:kafka.message.MessageAndMetadata[K,V]=>R)(implicitevidence$14:scala.reflect.ClassTag[K],implicitevidence$15:scala.reflect.ClassTag[V],implicitevidence$16:scala.reflect.ClassTag[KD],implicitevidence$17:scala.reflect.ClassTag[VD],implicitevidence$18:scala.reflect.ClassTag[R]):org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.InputDStream[R]), you should pass the `fromOffsets` as the 3rd parameter of createDirectStream(and don't forget about the 4th parameter `messageHandler`).

The `fromOffsets` parameter suppose to be a `collection.immutable.Map[TopicAndPartition, Long]`, we usually use immutable instead of mutable as possible in Scala.
You may transform the `dfoffsetArray` to `immutable.Map[TopicAndPartition, Long]` with the following:

```
val fromOffsets = dfoffsetArray.map( i =>
  TopicAndPartition(i(1).toString, i(0).toString.toInt) -> (i(2).toString.toLong)
).toMap
```

And the `messageHandler` is type of `(MessageAndMetadata[K, V]) ⇒ R)`, which deals key and value of messages. You can define a simple handler as the following:

```
val messageHandler =
  (mmd: MessageAndMetadata[String, String]) => (mmd.key, mmd.message)
```

Then your `createDirectStream` will look like...

```
KafkaUtils.createDirectStream[String, String, StringDecoder, StringDecoder,
  (String, String)](ssc, kafkaParams, fromOffsets, messageHandler)
```

Now you are free to do some transformation to your stream. Happy streaming!

---

I was tutored by [this](https://aseigneurin.github.io/2016/05/07/spark-kafka-achieving-zero-data-loss.html) article months ago. Maybe you will find it helpful.

Comment: Thanks a lot  happy streaming!